# custom action Bar color with appcompat for api 7

Tags: android, colors, android-actionbar, android-appcompat, android-actionbar-compat

I wanna to use custom colors for the action Bar for api 7

But i have problem:

`@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar` requires api 11 (current min is 7)

How can I do that with API 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `AppCompat` v21.

You can define your default style in `res/values/styles.xml`

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

    <!-- Set AppCompat’s color theming attrs -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_color</item>
</style>
```

If you would like to customize the color for API-V7 you can define a different style in `res/values-v7/styles.xml` with the same structure:

```
     <style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

        <!-- Set AppCompat’s color theming attrs -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_v7_color</item>
    </style>
```

I suggest you checking the [current distribution](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html?utm_source=suzunone) of Android. API 7 doesn't exist.

Comment: "API 7 doesn't exist". Heh, it used to! https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-2.1.html I remember when targeting API 4 was a worthwhile idea, but today you're right - we should pretend that API 7 and below do not exist. In fact API level 16+ only would be a good bet for new projects.

Comment: tanks a lot Mr Gabriele Mariotti

Answer (score 0):

Inherit theme from last *Appcompat* like this:

```
<style name="Theme.YourTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```